# Fading out an error box from codebehind

Tags: c#, asp.net, javascript, telerik

I have an error message box that gets displayed somewhat frequently (due to the nature of my program). Some sample code:

```
<asp:Panel runat="server" ID="ErrorMessagePanel" ClientIDMode="Static" CssClass="messageError"
Style="visibility: hidden;">
    <img src="../Images/RedClose.png" alt="close" class="messageCloseIcon" onclick="HideMessage('ErrorMessagePanel');" />
    <asp:Label runat="server" ID="ErrorMessage" ClientIDMode="Static" CssClass="messageErrorText" />
</asp:Panel>
```

The problem is that I don't want to force the user to always click the 'close' button, because these messages popup relatively frequently. I was thinking that a timed fade out would be a good option to follow. However, I can't work out how to call a timer to do a fadeout from my codebehind -- ie. Currently the codebehind sets 'display=block' to show the error, but I am not away that it can also launch some JS to fade out a box.

BTW, I am using Telerik controls, so would prefer to extend those rather than use the ASP Ajax fading extensions from Microsoft (I couldn't get them to work either, as it came up with a conflict with Telerik controls).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You won't be able to solve this strictly from code-behind code, you'll need some client side JavaScript. You should be able to [use jQuery with your Telerik controls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2314706/telerik-and-jquery) - it includes a [fadeOut](http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/) method suitable for your purposes.